# После переустановки плагина выводятся его старые настройки

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-плагины

Удаляю и заново устанавливаю плагин, но все равно в его настройках остаются изменения, которые я делал до удаления. Как это исправить?

Comment: Вручную удалить настройки плагина. Для этого, разумеется, надо знать, где плагин хранит свои настройки. Чаще всего это таблица `wp_options` в базе данных.

Comment: Для начала с пом плагинов оптимизации удалить ненужные transient-ы. Если не поможет - искать по базе и оч. аккуратно удалять. Но лучше - посмотреть в плагине какие optios где и как он пишет.

Comment: А для чего? Восстановить по умолчанию? А такой кнопки в плагине нету?

Comment: спасибо всем!!!